# How to change rows in css from 3x3 on desktop, to 2x4 on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code below shows 3 images per row for desktops.  When viewed on a mobile phone it shows 2 images, then 1, then 2, then 1, then 2, etc.

How can I make it when mobile to have 4 rows of 2, and still keep the 3 rows of 3 for desktop?

Thanks

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images  img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images  img-responsive" src=""></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images  img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images  img-responsive" src=""></img>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images  img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="images  img-responsive" src=""></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put them all in one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following format

```
(container)
  row
    col-md-4 col-xs-6
    col-md-4 col-xs-6
    ...(6x)
```

The columns will wrap below each other, so on medium views, you'll get 3 columns in a row, and on mobile views, 2 columns in a row.

If the trailing columns bother you, just add the classes `col-xs-offset-3` and `col-md-offset-2` (for example). The offsets will changed based on view. You can image this offset as an "invisible" column placed before the first in that new row.

Comment: Wow that was simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <img class="images img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>  
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="images  img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="images  img-responsive" src=""></img>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <img class="images img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>  
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="images  img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="images  img-responsive" src=""></img>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <img class="images img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>  
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="images  img-responsive" src="" alt="text"></img>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="images  img-responsive" src=""></img>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull all inside single `row` class and Use `col-sm-4 col-xs-6`

For width (≥768px) `col-sm-4` will work and for width (<768px) `col-xs-6` will work.